# Angular 5: get all objects of array based on property

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

I am working on an Angular 5 project and I'm trying to filter an array.

I have an array of objects. An object has the property color.
I am iterating over my array and I want to get all objects with the same color of my current object in the array. With the code below I seem to get only the first hit in the array and not all the elements.

This is my current code.

```
for(let object of this.objects){
let a: any = this.objects.find( a => a.color === object.color )
console.log(a);
// Do other stuff
}
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `.filter` instead of `.find`.

Comment: array has `#filter` method.

Comment: use `filter(....)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `filter` instead of `find`

```
  let a: any = this.objects.filter( a => a.color === object.color )
```